# Separate geopoint into lat and long

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, latitude-longitude

I have GeoPoint's in Parse that I need to separate into the latitude and longitude so that I can define a point. I was having issues so then I created two sting fields in Parse one just with the latitude and the other with just the longitude but now it will not work because it is not a number. I am new to Xcode and could use any help. Here is my current code:

```
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:EventLat.text
                                                      longitude:EventLong.text];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: PFGeoPoint has `latitude` and `longitude` properties. They are both floats. Just use... `theGeoPoint.latitude` etc... Also, your current code will not work because you are trying to put strings into something that is expecting floats.

Answer (score 3):

PFGeoPoint has `latitude` and `longitude` properties. They are both doubles. Just use... `theGeoPoint.latitude` etc... Also, your current code will not work because you are trying to put strings into something that is expecting doubles.

You can read the docs on PFGeoint here... https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFGeoPoint.html